# VSCode git error: fatal: failed to read object XXX: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: error: failed to push

Tags: git, git-push

I tired to push a new branch to github on windows 10 WSL1, with git 2.17.1. I fumbled around with the password prompt at the time, but it timed out. When I tried again, after it had hung up at least once, I now get this error message:

```
Pushing to https://github.com/repo/project
fatal: failed to read object <hash>: Permission denied
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/repo/project'
```

How do I undo this, so I can push again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message means that one of the objects that Git needs to push can't be read because of a permissions problem.

If these files are under your home directory in WSL, consider trying to run something like `chmod` or `chown` on your files so that they'll be accessible.  You can run `find .git -ls` to show the owner and permissions of your files.  Directories need to have read and execute permissions for your user and files need to have read permission.

If you're looking for a blunt approach, you can do this (substituting your user for `bk2204`):

```
$ sudo chown -R bk2204: .git
$ chmod -R u+rwX .git
```

If this is a Windows directory, then things are a little trickier.  You'll need to use the normal Windows permissions mechanisms to modify things.  If you're trying to store files for use by WSL in one of the special Windows directories, like Documents, don't: Windows restricts access to these by many programs, including some or all of WSL, and storing things there that need to be accessible by WSL is only going to cause problems.

Comment: Once I reset my wsl password and could sudo, this worked perfectly.